# Hold input data seached from database temporarily and show to view mvc and save it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to fetch data from sql based on the user input criteria and display it to user. At a time user can do multiple searches and all the result should display in the table below the search textbox.
After that on submit button i need to send these data that are displayed in table on view back to controller and save to database.

Comment: There are many ways to do this so you need to provide your code so we'll have a starting point.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Neither is it a replacement for tutorials or web searches.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

From controller to view you can send data either as json using json result action in ajaxcall or you can simply put data in either view bag  or view data.

public JsonResult FillProjectYearWise(string Year)
        {
            String s="name#value|1#2|3#4"

```
        return Json(Departments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

or 
 public JsonResult FillProjectYearWise(string Year)
        {
            FillDropDownServce objfilldropdown = new FillDropDownServce();

```
        List<SelectListItem> Departments = objfilldropdown.FillProjectYearWise(Year);

        return Json(Departments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

or
ViewData["value"]=your value

Or to access viewdata in view simply by '@ViewData["value"]'

For sending data from view to controller you can use ajax call or if you are doing post you can use hidden field and get that data on controller by RequestForm["Hiddenfieldname"].